# How do I get the first matched substring (of multiple lines)?

Tags: text-processing, sed, cut

I have a file where content looks like

```
/hello="somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff"
/hello="morestuffmorestuffmorestuffmorestuffmorestuffmorestuffmorestuff
       morestuffmorestuffmorestuffmorestuffmorestuff"
```

How would I get just

```
/hello="somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff"
```

I piped `sed` to just grab the `/hello` with `cut` delimited by '/' but I can't figure out how to get just the first substring.

command I used

```
sed -n '/hello/, /\"/ p' file.txt | cut -d "/" -f 2
```

For some reason it splits each substr into two fields; the first line and then the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use this:

```
sed -n '/hello/,/"$/p;/"$/q' infile
```

or this equality:

```
sed '/hello/,/"$/!d;/"$/q' infile
```

Or with `awk` also (assuming always first line has `hello`):

```
awk '/hello/ || 1;/"$/{exit}' infile
```

else use a flag to manage it.

```
awk '/hello/{prnt=1};prnt;/"$/{exit}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below sed command

```
sed '0,/hello.*/!s///' inputfile| sed '/^\/$/,$d'
```

output

```
/hello="somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
sed -n '/\/hello/,/"$/p;/"$/q' iputfile
```

output

```
/hello="somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff
       somestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuffsomestuff"
```